# Discrepancy between two methods two solve problems of rotational mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I am a high school student and I am very confused in a concept related to rotational dynamics , we know that

1)"$Γ=Iα$" and also**

2)**"$Γ=\text{rate of change of angular momentum}$"**

it means that if **moment of inertia** does not changes about an axis these two expressions are same but when I solve all problem then I get the correct answer on solving about each and every point when I apply this second equation

[image: sorry for this handwriting , this image shows an example on solving about any random "fixed point" through this method ,in this problem i have taken the moment of inertia about the center of mass to be 1/2kmR^2 where k is a constant and m and R are mass and radius of the object respectively and we have to find the acceleration of center of mass.]

but I cannot do the same problem about any random point by applying the first equation that I mentioned ,why is this happening ?If these two equation are exactly same why we cannot apply this 1st equation just like we have applied the second equation?

These two equations are just like "**$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}${if mass is constant}**" **and "$F=~\text{rate of change of momentum}$"** , we should have the freedom to apply any equation to any situation that we want but I think this is not the case here. Am I misunderstanding something because I don't see people to solve problems by applying the second equation that I mentioned above , but why? If we are reaching to the correct answer by applying this then why we don't  use it often?

Comment: It doesn't look like to me that you solved about any random point, you have solved your equation about the right end of the wheel, which is diametrically opossite to the point where the rope is attached. And BTW you can get the same result by applying both the equations about the same point

Comment: okay ,so please can you solve this question by applying the 1st equation about any "fixed point" rather then the Center of mass and point about which it actually performing pure rotation,                                                                                         mark my words , when you have chosen your point it should be fixed there and should not move along with that body , it would be very helpful if you guide me how to solve this question about the same point by applying the 1st equation or you can also share some link where it is done like this

Comment: Please don't write title in full capslock

Answer (score 1):

> but I cannot do the same problem about any random point by applying the first equation that I mentioned ,why is this happening ?

Because $\displaystyle{\vec{\tau} =\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \frac{d(I\vec{\omega})}{dt}}$

And the other equation $\vec{\tau} = I\vec{\alpha}$ is a simplified version of the same. You can't just apply this equation at any random point, because to get this simplified version we have to consider that $\displaystyle{\vec{\omega}\frac{dI}{dt}= 0}$ i.e. we assume that either the body has zero angular velocity or its moment of inertia doesn't vary with time (i.e. as its motion progresses) about the considered axis of rotation, which may or may not be true for every point in a system.

> If these two equation are exactly same why we cannot apply this 1st equation just like we have applied the second equation?

The equations aren't exactly the same, as noted above. But in certain situations where they mean the same thing, both give the same result.

Comment: thankyou very much, but can we do it like this, people should not have any problem with it.....is it the correct way?

Comment: yeah you can, but it is just hassle free to use the simplified version whenever possible.

Comment: and also if we apply the 1st eq. to a point which is R distance in right of the C.O.M ,the small particle present at this point have acceleration 2a if the C.O.M have acceleration "a" if i want to do it w.r.t this point we can do it by applying a pseudo force in opposite direction and still we get the right answer but i want to ask that, when we have chosen that point does that point get also rotate after some time along with the object ,or it moves parallel to the CO.M if it is moving parallel to the com THEN THIS HAVE ACCELERATION "a" not 2a" and in that case we don't get the correct answer

Comment: It rotates with the center of mass. I am not sure what you meant by parallel to the COM.

Comment: but suppose if i choose a point which moves with the same acceleration as that of C.O.M at a distance x rightward from it  and moves parallel to it ,means it is moving along with the COM parallel to its path then in this case MOMENT OF INERTIA ABOUT THAT POINT IS NOT CHANGING and if we apply the 1st equation here then also we don't get the correct answer {of course we have to apply a pseudo force which passes through C.OM in apposite direction of acceleration of point} but why?we should get the correct answer because this time MOMENT of inertia is constant about that point...